# Toroid core transformer: consequences of doubling the number of turns

Tags: inductor, impedance-matching, toroid

In a 2N3904 common emitter RF amplifier circuit that I am building, the designer uses a FT37-43 miniature core with an 8 turns primary : 2 turns secondary ratio to couple to the next stage.  I understand the purpose, it is impedance matching between the two stages.

My question is, what would the consequences be for using a 16:4 turns ratio instead of 8:2?  The ratio is the same so the impedance match should be the same but I am thinking don't do it for these reasons: the larger number of turns will reduce the power capacity as you will saturate the core at a lower signal level, the inductance seen at the collector of the 2N3904 would be four times as great, the Q factor drops because of the 2x resistance of the added wire, and physically fitting that many turns may not be possible.

Any other reasons?

Comment: Is your amplifier a resonant one ?

Comment: 8 turns on a core \$ 0.42uh/t^2 \$ yields 27uh...that may resonate with local capacitance near the design frequency. Or that local capacitance may reduce bandwidth of a broadband amplifier if you wind it with more turns or cause a gain peak in an otherwise-flat broadband amplifier.

Comment: No, the amplifier is not a resonant amplifier.  It is an approximate 9dB pre-amp for a signal around 10MHz.